# static Pointer to Custom Type stays nullptr after initialization with static not-null pointer of same Type

Tags: c++, pointers, static, namespaces

I have two namespaces with each a pointer to a class Window inside of one of the namespaces.

**Graphic.h**

```
namespace Graphic {

    //...
    class Window;

    //...
    void init();
    static Window* window;
}
```

**App.h**

```
namespace App{

    //...
    static Graphic::Window* mainWindow = nullptr;
    //...
    void init();
    void setupGraphic();
    //...
}
```

I am trying to initialize the `static Window* App::mainWindow`  with the `static Window* Graphic::window`

**Window.h**

```
#include "Graphic.h"
#include <SDL\SDL.h>

class Graphic::Window
{
public:
    Window(const char* pName = "OpenGL Window", 
           unsigned int pWidth = 1000, unsigned int pHeight = 700);
    ~Window();

    const char* name;
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
    SDL_Window* window;
};
```

**The Graphic::window is being initialized like so**

**Graphic.cpp**

```
#include "Graphic.h"

void Graphic::init(){
    window = new Window("Engine");
}
```

And after this initialization i try to initialize the `(static Window*)App::mainWindow` with `Graphic::window`

**App.cpp**

```
#include "App.h"
#include <Graphic\Graphic.h>
#include <Graphic\Window.h>

void App::setupGraphic()
{
    Graphic::init();
    App::mainWindow = Graphic::window;
}
```

But `App::mainWindow` stays nullptr, even though `Graphic::window` has successfully been initialized and has already been worked with in `Graphic::init()`. There are no compilation warnings/errors, all i get is an exception "App::mainWindow was nullptr."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In "Graphic.h", you have

```
static Window* window;
```

This statement is included in every translation unit (.cpp) that will `#include Graphic.h`. Therefore each unit will have its **own** variable `window`. What happens then is that `Graphic.cpp` assigns its own `window`, but `main.cpp` find its own variable `window` unchanged.

What you should do is the following:

In Graphic.h, declare `window` but don't define it:

```
extern Window* window;
```

And define it only once, in Graphic.cpp:

```
Window* Graphic::window = nullptr;
```

This way all the translation units will refer to the same global variable `window`.

You should do the same for the variable `Graphic::Window* mainWindow` defined in App.h.

```
extern Graphic::Window* mainWindow; // <-- in App.h
```

And

```
Graphic::Window* App::mainWindow = nullptr; // <-- in App.cpp
```

Comment: the App::mainWindow pointer still stays NULL... I also noticed that i can´t initialize it using ` = new Graphic::Window();`
Maybe its something about how `namespace App` and `class Graphic::Window` communicate?

Comment: okay i now also made App::mainWindow extern and defined it in App.cpp,
that fixed it. Thank you! I will have to get more comfortable with static and extern.

Comment: @stimulate that's because you dont have a constructor without arguments for the Window class, the default one is removed once you define another constructor.