# Access from View to modal dialog in SDI mfc application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, modal-dialog, sdi

I am a beginner at programming, and I should create an application for my final thesis. My app is created as SDI in MFC. I made a modal dialog that is opened from View. In the dialog, after button push, a measuring device should be connected to the app and should register several events. After the dialog is closed, coordinates from the connected device should be displayed in View in *Static Text*.

I can receive coordinates from the device, but there is a problem if I want to change *Static text* to show those coordinates with ShowWindowTextW(). If I understand, when DoModal() is called, the dialog is closed, and I cannot receive any values or functions from the dialog (therefore, I cannot change *Static Text* in View).

I found some examples of using pointers, but I don't know how to make it work. I am stuck here for some time and got several types of errors trying to solve them. My code:

MainWindow.cpp - View

```
void CMainWindow::OnFileConnect()
{
    CConnect dlgConnect;
    dlgConnect.DoModal();

}


// Displays measurement
void CMainWindow::UpdatePosition() {
    if (ManagedWrapper::LMFTracker) {
        LMF::Tracker::MeasurementResults::SingleShotMeasurement3D^ position = ManagedWrapper::newPosition;
        m_dro_x.SetWindowTextW((CString)position->Position->Coordinate1->ToString());
        m_dro_y.SetWindowTextW((CString)position->Position->Coordinate2->ToString());
        m_dro_z.SetWindowTextW((CString)position->Position->Coordinate3->ToString());
    }
}
```

Connect.cpp - dialog

```
// CConnect dialog

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CConnect, CDialogEx)

CConnect::CConnect(CWnd* pParent /*=nullptr*/)
    : CDialogEx(IDD_CONNECTION, pParent)
{

}

CConnect::~CConnect()
{
}

void CConnect::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_SIMULATOR, m_Simulator);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_CONNECT, m_Connect);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_IPADRESS, m_IPAdress);
 }


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CConnect, CDialogEx)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_CONNECT, &CConnect::OnBnClickedButtonConnect)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_SIMULATOR, &CConnect::OnBnClickedButtonConnectsimulator)
    END_MESSAGE_MAP()



void CConnect::OnBnClickedButtonConnect()
{
    CString ipAdressString;
    m_IPAdress.GetWindowText(ipAdressString);
    ConnectTo(ipAdressString);
}

void CConnect::OnBnClickedButtonConnectsimulator()
{
    ConnectTo(_T("Simulator"));
}

void CConnect::ConnectTo(CString ipAddress)
{
    if (ManagedWrapper::LMFTracker)
    {
        ManagedWrapper::LMFTracker->Disconnect();
    }

    Connection^ con = gcnew Connection();
    if (ipAddress != "0.0.0.0") {
        ManagedWrapper::LMFTracker = con->Connect(gcnew System::String(ipAddress));


            // Register some Events...

    }
}
```

In the variable *position* in CMainWindow.cpp is correct value so this part should be ok.
If I try to debbug the code I will get error in winocc.cpp: m_hWnd  Unable to read memory

```
void CWnd::SetWindowText(LPCTSTR lpszString)
{
    ENSURE(this);
    ENSURE(::IsWindow(m_hWnd) || (m_pCtrlSite != NULL)); // exception thrown in this line

    if (m_pCtrlSite == NULL)
        ::SetWindowText(m_hWnd, lpszString);
    else
        m_pCtrlSite->SetWindowText(lpszString);
}
```

I've got "Exception thrown: read access violation.
this was 0x250." in line commented above. 
In Call Stack there is:>    mfc140ud.dll!CWnd::SetWindowTextW(const wchar_t * lpszString=0x00e5b200) Line 242   C++

next one is:    Aplikacia.exe!CMainWindow::UpdatePosition() Line 95 C++

that is the line with m_dro_x in MainWindow.cpp (m_dro_x has value hWnd=???).

And another: Aplikacia.exe!ManagedWrapper::OnTargetPostionChanged(LMF::Tracker::Tracker^ sender={LMF::Tracker::AT960Tracker^}, LMF::Tracker::MeasurementResults::SingleShotMeasurement3D^ position={LMF::Tracker::MeasurementResults::SingleShotMeasurement3D^}) Line 66    C++

This is from Aplikacia.h file - here is the code:

```
    class CAplikaciaApp : public CWinApp
    {
    public:
        CAplikaciaApp() noexcept;


    // Overrides
    public:
        virtual BOOL InitInstance();
        virtual int ExitInstance();

    // Implementation
        afx_msg void OnAppAbout();
        DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    };

    extern CAplikaciaApp theApp;


    ref class ManagedWrapper {
    public:
        static CMainWindow* pMainWindow = nullptr;

        static LMF::Tracker::Tracker^ LMFTracker = nullptr;
        static LMF::Tracker::MeasurementResults::SingleShotMeasurement3D^ newPosition = nullptr;



        static void OnTargetPostionChanged(LMF::Tracker::Tracker^ sender, LMF::Tracker::MeasurementResults::SingleShotMeasurement3D^ position) {

            newPosition = position;
            pMainWindow->UpdatePosition();
        }

};
```

I found solution to my problem, very helpfull was this article:
[static Pointer to Custom Type stays nullptr after initialization with static not-null pointer of same Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200391/static-pointer-to-custom-type-stays-nullptr-after-initialization-with-static-not)

I added this line into MainWindow.h:

```
extern CMainWindow* pMainWindow;
```

Don't know if this is the best possible approach, but it works.

Comment: *"when DoModal() is called, the dialog is closed"* - That's not what `DoModal()` does. Instead, it displays a dialog, and doesn't return until the dialog is closed. While the dialog is displayed, the system still dispatches messages for you, so you can send messages to other windows in the system, trigger them to redraw, etc. It's hard to see what problem you are really trying to solve here.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. The problem is, that I have some value in variable "position" in MainWindow.cpp and when I try to pass it to m_dro_x.SetWindowText() it shows the mentioned error. I supposed that it has something to do with modal dialog.

Comment: If you get an error, post the *full* error message, plus the call stack that led up to that error.

Comment: I added what is written in call stack and exception thrown. And thank you for your effort.

Comment: The most common reason for an access violation is when dereferencing an invalid pointer. The only pointer in the line of code triggering the AV exception is the implicit `this` pointer. To understand why you are accessing a `CWnd`(-derived) class instance that doesn't exist, you're going to have to look at the call stack. The call stack consists of more entries than just the top. We already know, that the bug surfaces in this code. The call stack has the information, where the bug was installed.

Comment: I thought that the top line in call stack is the problem, but I was probably wrong. I added the next call stack lines. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to my problem, very helpfull was this article: [static Pointer to Custom Type stays nullptr after initialization with static not-null pointer of same Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200391/static-pointer-to-custom-type-stays-nullptr-after-initialization-with-static-not)

I added this line into MainWindow.h:

```
extern CMainWindow* pMainWindow;
```

Don't know if this is the best possible approach, but it works